# jQuery.ripples contained within a box/table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

https://github.com/sirxemic/jquery.ripples/

I've fooled around with this ripples jQuery plugin, though being only a novice i can't seem to find a way to contain the ripple effect within a specific area (such as a  or something) - I can only get it to work if i set it to apply to the entire body of the site.

I have tried editing the ripple controls to different css classes, though it breaks if i change the $('body') part to anything else.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
try {
    $('body').ripples({
        resolution: 512,
        dropRadius: 20, //px
        perturbance: 0.04,
    });
    $('main').ripples({
        resolution: 128,
        dropRadius: 10, //px
        perturbance: 0.04,
    });
}
```

Is there any way to get this plugin to only apply to a certain area of a page?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Difficult to say what is your problem if you don't provide your code ..

Anyway, have you read the first lines of the plugin code ?

```
// RIPPLES CLASS DEFINITION
// =========================

var Ripples = function (el, options) {
    var that = this;

    this.$el = $(el);
    this.$el.addClass('jquery-ripples');

    // If this element doesn't have a background image, don't apply this effect to it
    var backgroundUrl = (/url\(["']?([^"']*)["']?\)/.exec(this.$el.css('background-image')));
    if (backgroundUrl == null) return;
    backgroundUrl = backgroundUrl[1];
```

So, has the element that you are using a background image ?

Comment: Sorry for not providing more code, however at this moment i am only using the demo/example included in the package to get this to work, so there really isn't much to show :/

I have set a box with a backgorund image to try and get the effect, the background image is set through css.

Comment: Also, in the demo that you link, there are 2 ripples effects, one on body and the other on main. And main is limited to an area in the page, as you request.